# Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes mysql , entityframework(migration)

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, migration

I'm trying to use MySql and EntityFramework with Migrations, but something seems to be wrong.

This exception thrown:
Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

please help me :(

My new class :

```
public class user
{
    public user()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

}





public class PmtDbContext : DbContext
{
    static PmtDbContext()
    {
       Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<PmtDbContext, Migrations.Configuration>());

    }}





internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<PmtDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());

    }}
```

Comment: what do the usual key values for your objects look like? was the key column another type earlier?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro My keys in all classes are like this code:

[Key]
[Column ("id")]
Public int Id {get; set; }

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class PmtDbContext : DbContext
{
    static PmtDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(
            new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<PmtDbContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your code but it did not work. Now I have this error:
  Can not find file: './pmt_db/dbo@002epriorit@0kt@002dintegrationsart.frm' (errno: 2)

integrationsart  is a table in database

Comment: I forgot to say,I have the table renamed